# Displaying a number of total filtered elements by exposed filters

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-7

I haven't seen working solution for Drupal 7 to do this.
I have an exposed filters group which filters my views content to specified criteria and I'd like to display the number of found elements in a PHP block. I had working code for this :

```
<?php
  global $pager_total_items;
  print $pager_total_items[0] ;
?>
```

but it works ONLY in **Bartik theme** 
 so here's my question:
How can I display a number of total found/filtered elements in Drupal 7 views pager (any theme)..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this is to put this code in the PHP block:

```
$view = views_get_page_view();
print $view->query->pager->get_total_items();
```

and it works!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Views 3.7 in Drupal 7 right now and finally found out you simply can add a result summary `Global: Result summary` to the header/footer.